# Pass @to_whom and @from_whom to a Rails 3 mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mailer

How can i pass two users (@to_whom and @from_whom) to a mailer from the controller. I have only been able to get one passed, e.g.:

```
UserMailer.invitation_email(@to_whom).deliver
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass multiple parameters:

```
UserMailer.invitation_email(@to_whom, @from_whom).deliver
```

Just make sure your `invitation_email` method is set up to accept all the parameters:

```
def invitation_email(to_whom, from_whom)
  ...
end
```

Comment: the details... i forgot to expand the parameters the on the mailer. Thank you!